# How do I create and add a value to a variable from a file

Tags: c++

I have a .dat file that looks like this

```
x -3
r 6
t -2
a 4
w 65
u 83
l 1
m 8888
```

From this file I am trying to create and then assign a value to the variable using infile. For example, `int x = -3`. I can read in all the values but my problem is how to do what I want after I've read them in.

```
 infile.open("test.dat");

while (infile.peek() != EOF) {
    //infile >> check; //gets string from file
    //cout << check;
    getline(infile,check);
   //cout << check << endl;
   }
```

From here would I use a stack and then pop them later?

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: how about a std::map<char, int>?

Comment: One possible interpretation of your question is you can read the file, but don't know how keep the data in a form accessible by the variable name.  Could you expand your question to more clearly what you expect after you read your file.  My guess would be you might be wanting to store them in a `std::map<std::string, int>` as you read them in

Comment: "my problem is how to do what I want after I've read them in."  What do you want to do after you read them in?  "From here would I use a stack and then pop them later?"  Depends on what you want to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like the following?

```
int value, x;
char variable;

infile.open("test.dat");

while (infile.peek() != EOF) {
    infile >> variable; // get variable
    infile >> value; // get value

    switch(variable){
        case 'x':
            x = value;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Unknown variable." << endl;
            break;
    }
}
```

Edit: Based on UKMonkey and Infixed suggestions, you could also just store the values in a map.

```
map<char, int> variables;

while (infile.peek() != EOF) {
    infile >> variable; // get variable
    infile >> value; // get value

    variables[variable] = value;
}
```

You can output the values from the map.

```
for(auto itr : variables){
    cout << itr.first << " : " << itr.second << endl;
}
```

or something like

```
cout << variables['x'] << endl;
```

Comment: This guy is a genius. So simple but makes sooo much sense.